# mod_rewrite all domains to one tld

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm looking for a way to transparently (without redirect) rewrite all domains to the same domain but one tld. So:

random.domain.tld -> random.domain.local

where there is an unknown number of segments before the tld, the tld itself is unknown, and the tld will never have dots in it (like co.uk) so it should be simply everything before the last do and everything after the last dot.

I've tinkered around with this for a while with no luck:

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.([^\.]*?)$ $1.local [L]
```

Comment: So you are planning a honeypot. Question is: for protection or for scam?

Comment: Neither. We need to access subdomain.domain.local and 20 others which live on each of our developers' virtual machines using subdomain.domain.developername in the easiest way possible that doesn't involve changing our framework configs.

Comment: The easiest way would be to simply make local DNS entries pointing to your development system.

Comment: We have dns set up to allow each developer to have their own tld on our local network. Just need to translate that personal tld to the real one in apache on their local machine without reconfiguring our app. The idea is that when a new developer joins us and sets up their development vm, we add them to the office dns and Apache on the vm will automatically translate any thing not ending in .local to .local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that with a simple RewriteRule, since that only works on the path of a url. Instead you require a RewriteCond to get an additional reference:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !\.local$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.local$1 [P,QSA]
```

A general hint for such rewriting rules: *if* you have access over the http server configuration then you should always prefer to put such rules into the host configuration section. .htaccess style files are notoriously error prone, they make things complex, are hard to debug and slow the server down. They are only an alternative, if you *do not* have access to the http server configuration.

If however the goal simply is to have a temporary way to "redirect" request for testing purposes, then often the easier and more elegant way is to make local DNS entries overriding the real addresses of the domains to be tested.

Comment: This seems to be just about there.. only problem is it's giving a forbidden error on the frontend_dev.php because it comes after this line in the htaccess "RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /frontend_dev.php [QSA,L]". Is this a totally separate problem?

Comment: Not sure I got you right: you mean you have _additional_ rules inside some .htaccess style file? If the rule in your comment comes _before_ those posted by me, then because of the `L` flag you specified no further rewriting will take place.

Comment: Just read your edit. Yes we have full access to the apache server config. Thank you for pointing that out. Yes we have additional rules in the htaccess. This is a symfony app which rewrites all requests to a single front controller (in our case called frontend_dev.php. I'll tinker around with this a little more. I suspect your answer is what we need, just need to make it work a little better with our particular framework setup.

Comment: Sure, you might have to try around a little in that case. Please note that I just made another change to the rule set: I added a second RewriteCond to prevent an endless rewriting loop...